# Issue with Sitecore home page

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

Hi guys i am new to Sitecore and asp.net and iis.
I have installed all on my server 2008.

When i got to /localhost/sitecore/Website/sitecore.

I get following error. Can anyone help me what is this and what should i need to do.

```
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 


Line 2575:      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
Line 2576:    </httpHandlers>
Line 2577:    <membership defaultProvider="sitecore"> -- this line shows errr
Line 2578:      <providers>
Line 2579:        <clear />
```

Comment: Can you access your site at http://localhost/?

Comment: When i open localhost then it opens IIS page not sitecore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have set up the site as a Virtual Directory in the IIS. Sitecore needs to run as a standalone site with its own application-pool. If you are using IIS6 and already have a site running on the default website you can use IISAdmin to add more sites http://iisadmin.codeplex.com/.

Hope this helps.